# understanding crockford's function that returns a function with a variable value

Tags: javascript, scope

i was just watching Douglas Crockford videos and he gave the following exercise to do :

> write a function, that when passed a variable, returns a function that
>   if called , returns the value of the variable.

so i wrote the following function :

```
function funcky(o) {
    return function send(o){ // notice the o in send
      return o;
    }
  }

  var x = funcky(3);

  console.log(x()); // i get undefined why ??
```

notice the `o` in send. i have been programming javascript for a while now , but i still don't understand why i get undefined ??

crockfords solution was as follows :

```
  function funcky(o) {
    return function send(){
      return o;
    }
  }

  var x = funcky(3);

  console.log(x()); // get 3 now .
```

now how come this solution works and mine does't ? i don't see much of a difference in my solution and nothing is obviously wrong that i see. can anybody explain please ?

Comment: Crockford is returning a function that takes no parameters. It gets it's parameters from the outer function. Your function takes parameters which you'd have to supply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with the scope of `o`. When you write:

```
return function send(o){ // notice the o in send
  return o;
}
```

The scope of `o` is local to the function send. But, if you write:

```
return function send(){
  return o;
}
```

The scope of o is not local to the function send, but is local to the scope of funcky.

So, when you write `function send(o){/*...*/}` what is really happening is that `o` becomes an argument, and would need to be called like this: `funcky()(10)`, but what you want to be able to do is `funcky(10)()`.

EDIT:

For more information about variable scope in JavaScript, please see [this very detailed answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript).

Comment: so basically javascript has function scope but no block scope i guess !

Answer (score 4):

The `o` in the `send(o){` is where you are making a mistake. It is not 'inheriting' the `o` from the original parent's arguments. Putting it inside that function declaration is creating a new `o`, inside a new scope of that function.

`send` isn't passed anything when called, and it returns its first argument so it returns `undefined`.

Your code, annotated:

```
function funcky(o) {
    return function send(o){ // DECLARES NEW VARIABLE, happens to have same name
      return o; //returns the first argument passed to send
    }
  }

var x = funcky(3); //nothing is passed to the inner function send

console.log(x()); // undefined due to lack of arguments
```

A slightly clearer example of what is actually occuring:

```
function funcky(o) {
   return function send(someArgument){
     return someArgument; //return o; here would find the correct o, the first arg of funcky
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function funcky(o) {
    return function send(o){ // notice the o in send
      return o;
    }
}
```

Your inner function's `o` parameter shadows the `o` originally passed to `funcky`. So when you write `var x = funcky(3);`, x is just a `send` function which expects a parameter to return, there's nothing captured in a closure.

(In other words, x doesn't have a reference to the original `o` - 3 in your case, because by the name o it calls the parameter that x itself is called with).

Answer (score 2):

Because of scope.

The function send overwrites the var o in its inner scope.

```
function funcky(o) {
// o here is whatever you passed in funcky
  return function send(o){
  // now o here is whatever you pass in send
  // since you didn't pass anything the result is undefined
    return o;
  }
}
```

Check this other example

```
function funcky(o) {
  return function send(a){
    console.log(a);
    console.log(o); // this o is the parent o
    return o;
  }
}

var x = funcky(3);

console.log(x());
```